# For loops don't log anything

Tags: javascript, math

I'm using javaScript to solve a math problem to get some data about integers within a specific range, with a special condition.

I'm using a `for` loop to keep incrementing the number within the range (1 to 2000). Another `for` loop checks each digit of the integer if it contains a `7`, and if so, logs it to the console.

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i < 2001; i++) {
    for (var index = 0; index <= i.length; index++) {
        if (i.substring(index, index + 1) == 7) {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, I'm getting no output, just `undefined`. No error messages either.

---

The inner loop seems to be at fault.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 2001; i++) {
    for (var index = 0; index <= i.length; index++) {
        console.log(index); //No output - undesired
    }
    console.log(i); //Prints out i from 1 to 2000 - desired
}
```

Why is my code not logging the appropriate numbers?

Comment: since `i` is a number, it dosent have length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because numbers don't have string properties. Convert it to a string

```
for (var i = 1; i < 2001; ++i)
  for (var i_str = i.toString(), index = 0; index <= i_str.length; ++index)
    if (i_str.substring(index, index + 1) == 7)
      console.log(i);
```

Comment: +1 for no braces, and solved my problem.  btw, you can use `.length` directly with `toString()` to remove the need of the extra variable (`i_str`) like so: `index <= i.toString().length`.

Comment: @scriptHero Yes, but then you will recreate thestring at each iteration. And you need the string for `substring` too.

Comment: Is there an complication with recreating the string per iteration?  I'm uncertain, but for 2000 checks, performance shouldn't be too significant a problem.

Comment: @scriptHero `2000` means numbers have up to 4 digits. That would be 4 string conversions in the loop condition and 4 in the `if` statement, so 8 in total, for each number. So my answer improves the performance up to a 8 factor. It's nothing extraordinary, but why not?

Answer (score 2):

`i` is an integer.  `i.length` is undefined.  `length` is a property of string and array objects, but not integers.  Therefore the `for` loop is comparing `index <= undefined`.  This comparison is `false` and you never actually enter the `for` loop.

Comment: This is only half the answer. The other half is that `0 <= undefined` is `false`.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, it is coerced to `NaN`, not `0`.

Answer (score 1):

As started above `i` is a numbers and does not have string properties. It reads nicer without the double loop. Use `match` instead:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 2001; ++i) {
    if (i.toString().match(/7/g) != null) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"It reads nicer..."_ Sure, it _looks_ better. But is it better than Oriol's solution _performance-wise_?

Comment: Yes, this is a lot quicker. (254ms vs 345ms). Not that it matters on a loop of 2k but it will be a huge saving on bigger numbers/loops. Said that, I would go with readability until there is a need to optimise. Which in this case will never happen as the loop and number is hard coded.